# "Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdfd" when serialize

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc, doubly-linked-list

Im trying to store data with doubly linked lists.
So I made a while statement that passes every node into the archive.

```
if (ar.IsStoring())
{
    while (Actual)
    {
        ar << Actual->name;
        ar << Actual->adresse;
        ar << Actual->email;
        ar << Actual->fax;
        ar << Actual->firma;
        ar << Actual->geburtsdatum;
        ar << Actual->geschlecht;
        ar << Actual->land;
        ar << Actual->ort;
        ar << Actual->plz;
        ar << Actual->telefon;
        ar << Actual->vorname;
        Actual = Actual->next;
    }
}
```

This works. My problem is to load the variables. It is 1:1 the same. (Instead of << to >>).

I alwany get an error "Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdfd".
I dont really know why. 
There is an error with `Actual = Actual->next;` **at the top of the function**.

If you need it, here is my full Serialize function:

```
void CDatenbankDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    Actual = Start;
    Actual = Actual->next;
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        while (Actual)
        {
            ar << Actual->name;
            ar << Actual->adresse;
            ar << Actual->email;
            ar << Actual->fax;
            ar << Actual->firma;
            ar << Actual->geburtsdatum;
            ar << Actual->geschlecht;
            ar << Actual->land;
            ar << Actual->ort;
            ar << Actual->plz;
            ar << Actual->telefon;
            ar << Actual->vorname;
            Actual = Actual->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (Actual)
        {
            ar >> Actual->name;
            ar >> Actual->adresse;
            ar >> Actual->email;
            ar >> Actual->fax;
            ar >> Actual->firma;
            ar >> Actual->geburtsdatum;
            ar >> Actual->geschlecht;
            ar >> Actual->land;
            ar >> Actual->ort;
            ar >> Actual->plz;
            ar >> Actual->telefon;
            ar >> Actual->vorname;
            Actual = Actual->next;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope you can help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks

Comment: Do not ever store pointers when serializing data. Pointers will not be meaningful when deserializing them. Also, do not ever leave pointers uninitialized. You need to provide code for the c'tor of your `Actual`. In essence, you should not even use pointers in C++.

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd is a magic value, designed to crash your program when you get the code wrong.  It tells you that you are using an object that was already deleted.  So Actual->next is garbage, not creating the object that you deserialize is a very notable flaw in the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

When reading, you will have to create a new object for each entry in the archive, something like:

```
while (!ar.IsBufferEmpty())
{
    Actual->next = new TypeOfActual;
    Actual = Actual->next;

    ar >> Actual->name;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Each object you deserialize must be created before you can deserialize it.

Comment: @Michael Almost correct. However, the MFC serialization also builds upon MFC's class factories as implemented through [`DECLARE_DYNCREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56302tyt.aspx) and friends. If you want to serialize/deserialize compound structures you should consider making them dynamically creatable.